# Adding Apache to User Group

Tags: 12.04, permissions, apache2

We have a small LAMP server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which contains a few sites. Access to the vhosts directories is set to `root:AndSpecialSFTPGroup`. This works fine in general. However, some of the sites run on a CMS which need write access to particular folders. This is now not working, because the Apache user is `www-data`.

Simple question: Is OK to add the `www-data` to the `AndSpecialSFTPGroup` group in order to grant it `rwx` permissions. Or is this the wrong approach altogether.

Or should the owner of the website folders be `www-data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could approach this, but you can add `www-data` to that group like so:

```
sudo usermod -a -G AndSpecialSFTPGroup www-data
```

As far as "Is it the *right* way to do this?" Like I said, there are many ways to accomplish this, but it's similar to asking me what's the best way to arrange your desk. In many facets of IT, development, and OS, there are choices left up to preference.

This is the way I prefer to handle permissions like this **because** if I screw something up, I can easily remove the user from the group again. You might like using `chown` to give all the files to `www-data`, or something else altogether.

My way is **a** right way to do this, which is why I most likely won't get flagged for being subjective, but there are other ways. (Like I mentioned `chown`, create another user, `chmod` to change the permissions overall, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, Kyle.

What I am mostly 'wondering' about, is if this is an appropriate approach....

Comment: It is @AdrianWagner

Comment: @AdrianWagner See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks again, Kyle. That was the answer I needed. I knew I could solve it this way, but was wondering if there were be no-no's attached to it.

Comment: `useradd` (like `usermod`) is always a bit dangerous -- be careful to use `-G` and **not** `-g`.

Comment: Just a note that it appears to be necessary to restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart` in order to apply the permission of the group it's been assigned to.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I got to it via Google as the top result for "ubunut add apache to a group".

Since the *www-data* user already exists the command should be **usermod**, which is used to modify an existing user.

```
sudo usermod -a -G AndSpecialSFTPGroup www-data
```

You can then confirm the change by executing

```
id www-data
```

Comment: `usermod` is always a bit dangerous -- be careful to use `-G` and **not** `-g`.